# Which is more efficient: respond_to? or a method that does nothing?

Tags: ruby

This is something I've wondered about for years: is it more efficient to check if an object has a method and then, if it does, call the method, OR always have a method that does nothing, always call that method, and subclasses should override that method as needed.

Consider this example:

```
class Base
    def mymethod
        respond_to?(:hook) and hook()
        puts 'stuff in mymethod'
    end
end

class SubClass < Base
    def hook
        puts 'stuff in hook'
    end
end
```

So in this situation we've basically added an event handler. If a subclass has a method called `hook` then that method is called in `mymethod`. This is a pretty common design technique. But, of course, that requires checking if the method exists.

Another technique to implement the same result would be to design `Base` like this:

```
class Base
    def mymethod
        hook()
        puts 'stuff in mymethod'
    end

    def hook
    end
end
```

Now you don't have to check every time if there's a method called `hook`, but you do have to call that method every time, even if it does nothing.

So which is more efficient? Which is easier for the programmer to understand? Is the difference so small that it's merely a matter of personal preference?

Comment: Which is more efficient? Use `Benchmark` and figure it out. I don't see any effort from you at all to answer this on your own, and it's super easy to figure out. Please make at least _some_ effort on your own first, and explain what you've tried and where you're now stuck. What's easier or is it a matter of personal preference? That's purely opinion-based and [is off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), so my recommendation is to remove those questions.

Comment: I've made various efforts over the years to find a difference, with inconclusive results. I'm not an experienced benchmarker, which is why I'm going to a place where I can ask benchmarking questions. As for an opinion being off-topic, it's probably also off-topic that negative-spirited responses like yours just make the world a little worse, and that maybe you should consider the tone of your posts.

Comment: Why not just use the safe navigation operator (`self&.hook`)?

Comment: @max: I don't think I understand what you mean. I put self&.hook in the code and it just gave me an error if there's no hook method: undefined method `hook' for #<Base:0x0000563ade973e38>

Comment: Sorry I just had a brain fart, of course it won't work since it just guards against calling on nil and not if the method is underfined.

Comment: I've had cerebral flatulence on more than one occasion. :-)

Comment: If you've made various efforts over the years, and you have benchmarked this yourself before, then you must include those examples in your post. Why would you intentionally create more work for the people you're asking for help by not including the work you've already done? You want us to duplicate your work? That's the least polite thing I can imagine from someone asking others for help. This post screams "I've tried nothing and I'm all out of options." You REALLY need to take a moment to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking. I'm happy to help people. (if they help themselves first)

Comment: I'm sorry you feel that way.

Comment: "Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%." -- Donald Knuth in "Structured Programming with go to Statements"

Comment: "I'm sorry you feel that way."? Really? @anothermh is offering you some good advice for working with SO. "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)", 
"[Writing The Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)"
and "[How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)" are very good reading when asking on SO.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: It's so trivial that you shouldn't care.

Long answer:

```
require 'benchmark'

class Base
  def mymethod
    respond_to?(:hook) and hook()
  end
end

class SubClass < Base
  def hook
  end
end

class Parent
  def mymethod
    hook
  end

  def hook
  end
end

class Child < Parent
end

s = SubClass.new
c = Child.new
n = 10000000
Benchmark.bm(7) do |x|
  x.report(:respond_to?) { n.times {s.mymethod} }
  x.report(:empty) { n.times {c.mymethod} }
end
```

Result:

```
                   user     system      total        real
respond_to?    1.263308   0.011612   1.274920 (  1.327659)
empty          0.789442   0.010208   0.799650 (  0.900536)
```

So using `respond_to?` is slightly slower than using empty method.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you! I admit I hadn't thought of benchmarking this specific case. It wasn't that there wasn't "any effort" on my part (as was suggested above)... I actually spent some time carefully putting together an example, writing a question, proofreading it, etc. I just didn't know the answer before I posted the question, which, I thought, was why you post questions. Thanks!

Comment: There was literally zero effort on your part. You said "given this example which is faster?" without making any effort to determine which one was faster. You could have tried to benchmark it, then posted a question about "how do I benchmark this? What I'm trying isn't working." Instead, you said "someone benchmark this for me and post the results. I can't be bothered to try." That's zero effort. There's a clear difference.

Comment: I'm sorry you feel that way.

Answer (score 0):

Offtopic a bit, but I'd say using `respond_to?` with an implicit receiver in the way you propose is a code smell - it means that you are doing some weird things that break subtyping ([LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)).

Sometimes it might be really necessary for some black metaprogramming magic, debugging, hotfixing the live app etc - but I bet in such cases you won't ask questions like this (you will know for sure why do you do this, end efficiency will be less of a problem for sure).

So, as for me, the question is not about efficiency. *Always* "respect" (follow) LSP if you can and play with `respond_to?` only if you must (and in this case performance might be not the main criteria)

Comment: Very interesting stuff. I admit most of that article is over my head, but I did get some takeaways. If I understand it correctly, LSP says that, in my example, anything of a subclass of Base should operate exactly like something of Base itself. So anything a Car does, a StationWagon should do. If Car doesn't specify miles per gallon, then a StationWagon can any mpg without not being a car anymore. But if a Car has to fit into a specified parking parking space size, then an 18Wheeler can't be considered a car.

Comment: Also what I'm hearing you say is don't metaprogram when you could just program. That seems a reasonable philosophy.

Answer (score 0):

`respond_to?` will always be slower. It will incur at least one (in the negative case), and possibly two (in the positive case) method calls. The empty base method case, on the other hand, is just the one method call.

Method calls are fast, but if you're really trying to micro-optimize, all else held constant, reducing the number of method calls will result in faster code.

Comment: Ah, I see your point. You're basically saying that in both situations you're always making at least one function call, but in one case you're sometimes making two. So it makes sense to just always make one call. FWIW, I also think having a do-nothing method is a little more comprehensible, though I guess that's a matter of (dare I say it) opinion.